# jsp- session -how to use old session (if exist) but not create a new one

Tags: jsp

I am leaning about sessions in jsp.

I have a application which send login and pass to servlet.
If they correct servlet create a new session and send a page.jsp to client.
Page checks if any session exist if not not create new one and blocks user.

I want to block a possibility to access to this page when there is any session,
but if I use:

`<%@ page session=false %@>`

I will loose access to  old session
(if she exist). 
How to force jsp to connect to old session but not to create new one?

If I miss something I will by very grateful for :

- best practices
- links, explanation etc
- any advices :)

Comment: ??? the title of you question does make no sense: not create if not exists...

Comment: thanks for message :) I hope that this one is more understandable  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *create* a session. You can only *get* a session, and this will return a previously created session (if present), or create one and return it (if no session present yet).

Even non logged-in users can have a session. In fact, they will have one by default if they browse to a JSP which doesn't have `session=false`. The authentication should simply get
the session, and store some `authenticated` flag (or `userId` token) in the session.

If you don't want authenticated users to go to the login page, then when they go to this page, check if the `userId` token is already in the session, and redirect to some other page.